# Is an embedding a representation of a word or its meaning?

Tags: terminology, word-embedding, embeddings

What does the term "embedding" actually mean?

An embedding is a vector, but is that vector a representation of a word or its meaning? Literature loosely uses the word for both purposes. Which one is actually correct?

Or is there anything like: *A word is its meaning itself*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An embedding is a representation of a word that can be used as a proxy for some of its linguistic properties.

The 'human' representation of a word, a sequence of letters and other symbols, is not related at all to its meaning or use in actual text. It only serves as a look-up key into our cognitive language processing facility (however that actually works) which enables us to understand the meaning in the context of its usage. However, a computer system does not have such a facility.

In order to convert the character string into something more usable for language processing, embeddings are created. These are typically vectors describing other words that surround a word in question (as the meaning of a word depends on its context). There are obvious problems with ambiguities (eg is *bank* the side of a river or a place where you deposit money?), but there are probably ways around that.

So the embedding (a vector) represents the usage of a word, which strongly correlates with its meaning. Because words as character sequences are useless for most sub-symbolic processing, the terms *embedding* and *word* are possibly used interchangably.

Answer (score 2):

Although we have had multiple similar questions (see [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/25467/2444), [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11285/2444) and [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/5408/2444)) and it seems to me that you focused on *word embeddings* (probably because you were not aware of the application of embeddings to other contexts), in addition to what is stated in [the other answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/28012/2444), it's important to note that the concept of an *embedding* does not just apply to words. For example, there are also *code embeddings* (see e.g. [code2vec](https://code2vec.org/)) and *graph embeddings* (see e.g. [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-data-science/graph-embeddings/)), and there are probably other examples. The linked posts contain answers that explain what an embedding and embedding space generally are, so you may want to read them.